# Why are stand-up comedians using corded microphones?

Tags: production, comedy

I've watched a smattering of Netflix productions of stand-up comedians from the last five years and I'm confused: **Why are they using corded microphones on stage?**

I'm almost certain it's not for technical reasons, since other stage performers have been using cordless microphones – including unobtrusive lavalier and headset mics – and for decades.

I can imagine that for stand-up comedians the microphone may feel like or actually serve as a prop.  But is the *cord* a prop?  (The fact that I find it so conspicuous makes me think it is actually getting in their way as they pace the stage, dragging it and trying not to step on it or tangle it.)

Comment: If you're in a band and the signal cuts out, the rest of the band covers that up.  If you're the only one onstage and the signal cuts out, you could lose the punchline.  You might also note that a lot of "musicians" musicians use corded equipment for the same reason; it matters.

Comment: Dave Chapelle during "Killing them Softly" used cordless mic. I would say it's either venue setting or comedian aesthethic choice (you know who use headset mics? people who sell you bullshit and need hands free to cast a spell).

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY what does that tell about Ricky Gervais? He uses a headset mic for his Humanity Netflix special (and I think he uses it in others too)

Comment: I suppose it's a combination of what's in the comments: some are preference, some must be venue limitations.

Comment: @Luciano did he does that thing with his hands when he's pretending he's masturbating? If yes then, tadam, casting a spell.

Comment: Similar microphone cases for talk shows and the like too, usually you will see the people being interviewed sat there with a small clip-on mic on their clothing but I have noted on some programs ( early morning UK breakfast TV for instance is a good example ) there is an angled mic or two on the table, not the handheld ones - the desk or tabletop type with a base.

Comment: I think a wireless microphone that's attached to the collar of the suit is very better. Because the stand-up comedians use their hands very much in their shows. So with a microphone that they take in their hands their voice can be so unstable. They move their hands very much.